# Multiplying double and storing it in an Integer in C program

Tags: c, double

I am pretty new to C programming and I don't know what is wrong with my code. I try to store a multiplied double into an integer but it stores 1 instead of 2.

Here is the code:

```
temp = money*100;
printf("\n%d remains.....", temp);
money -= ((double)temp / 100);
totalPennies = temp / pennies;
```

Output:

[image]

Here is the full code:
https://github.com/CoyAri/Coin_Dispense/blob/main/here

Comment: Try to put all relevant code here. Why do you do fabs() when negative instead of setting to 0 ? Other point : you can try to only work with integer and use the decimal just for display. Also for debug show more decimals to be sure about double rounding artifacts.

Comment: It's due to floating point roundoff. The number is less than two by some tiny little amount that normally isn't displayed when printing it.  To fix it, rather than doing `i = d;`, instead do `i = d + 0.5;`.  That will will round the value (assuming `d` is positive - if it can be negative, then you can use `i = round(d);` instead).

Comment: Links to external sites may rot in the future, rendering the question invalid so questions must be self contained with a [mcve]